# Remove quotes to use result as dataset name

Tags: r, string

I've got a vector with a long list of dataset names. E.g

```
myvector<-c('ds1','ds2,'ds3')
```

I'd like to use the names **ds1..ds3** to write a file, taking the file name from the vector. Like this:

```
write.csv(dataset[i],file=paste(myvector[i],'.csv',sep='')
```

with dataset being **d1...ds3**, but without quotes. How can I remove the quotes and refer to the real dataset, and not to the string?

Thanks in advance,      p.

Comment: Try `lst <- mget(myvector)` and `lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) write.csv(lst[[i]], file=paste(myvector[i], '.csv', sep=''))`

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be working, still I haven't check rcran for "mget", totally new for me. Btw there's one parenthesis missing at the end, just in case anyone copy-pastes it like I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the values with `get` or `mget` (for multiple objects)

```
 lst <- mget(myvector)
 lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) write.csv(lst[[i]], 
            file=paste(myvector[i], '.csv', sep=''))
```